# Pyinstaller: не получается запросить права администратора (UAC)

Tags: python, windows, uac

Добрый вечер!
Вопрос для гуру Python.
Есть программа, которая преобразовывается в exe с помощью pyinstaller. Всё бы хорошо, но мне надо, чтобы при запуске полученного исполнимого файла на Win с UAC происходил запрос на повышение прав. Данного эффекта не удаётся достичь, используя параметр –-uac-admin.
Python 3.4.4, pyinstaller 3.2
Подскажите, плиз, как реализовать запрос админских прав для моего случая?

Comment: На основном сайте пишут что необходимо приложить файл манифеста рядом с exe. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43068920/pyinstaller-uac-not-working-in-onefile-mode

Answer (score 2):

При использовании в pyinstaller параметра --uac-admin должен создаться манифест(по-моему он находится в папке **build**), который нужно добавить в собираемый exe файл с помощью параметра --manifest.